# Strange thing with concatenation and adding in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have some code for convolution in Verilog where I need to generate the result after multiplying the pixels with kernel and adding bias.

After I multiply with the kernel, the value is in signed hex 44 bits with 12 bits integer and 32 bits decimal (conv_result=ffec53a50dd). The bias value is 01310 in signed hex 20 bits with 4bits integer and 16bits decimal.

So I sign extend it to 44 bits by {{8{K0_bias[19]}},K0_bias,16'h0000}. K0_bias is 01310.

Now if I directly add conv_result + {{8{K0_bias[19]}},K0_bias,16'h0000}, I get signed 45 bit result =0ffed84a50dd but if I first store the value of {{8{K0_bias[19]}},K0_bias,16'h0000} in a signed register(bias_value) of 44 bits and then add conv_result+bias_value I get signed 45 bit result =1ffed84a50dd.

I need 1ffed84a50dd. But I don't understand why there is this difference in MSBs. Can someone explain if I am missing something?

Comment: Do you have code for this?

Comment: Yes, I have written code by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result from a concatenation operation is always unsigned, even if all its operands are signed. Also, a select of a signed value is unsigned even if selecting all the bits. That means your addition becomes unsigned.

So you need to extend the sign out to 45 bits by replicating it by 9 instead of 8.

Comment: Thanks, I get that concatenation operation is always unsigned. But why store the sign extension in a register first and then add leads to the correct signed result? Sorry, I still didn't get it.

Comment: Because you stored the 44-bit result of the concatenation in a 44-bit _signed_ register.  That register gets sign extended by 1-bit to the 45-bit signed addition.